# Which syllable do you stress in the word <forward> as a *verb*

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

When you use forward as a verb, which syllable is stressed? (**for**ward vs for**ward**)

> I forwarded the email as soon as I read it
>
> This button forwards the message.

Comment: You can look this up easily in a dictionary that provides the word in phonetic writing like this:  **/ˈfɔː.wəd/** . The **'** before the **f** indicated that for is the stressed syllable. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forward

Comment: You may be getting misled by [forearm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/forearm), which as a noun (lower part of arm) is stressed on the first syllable, but as a verb (to arm or prepare beforehand) it's stressed on the *second* syllable.

Comment: Thanks JavaLatte. I did already but I was not sure whether there is only one way or not to utter the word. I use many dictionaries. @choster below is misled by the seemingly simple question. Would an average native speaker know there is only one version of pronouncing it without referring to many dictionaries or doing some research?

Answer (score 3):

It's always pronounced **for**ward, regardless of how it's used.

Comment: Please do not answer dictionary lookup questions; it only encourages more.

Comment: Just to let my fellow posters that I did what @choster advised already, and in fact I consulted several ones. That is before posting this question. Not every question but this very question was welcome somewhere else I think because they recognize that not all vocabulary are the same.